# I have problem in removing some symbols from Dataset with Regular Expression.Symbols like - ï¼Œ

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have problem in removing some symbols from Dataset with Regular Expression

```
import re
with open (r'C:\Users\Ashutosh Singh\Desktop\RedCarpet\1.txt','w') as f:
file = re.sub(r'[^\w]',' ',f)
```

Output:

```
  TypeError                                
  Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-2-e0ce1f14d91b> in <module>()
  1 with open (r'C:\Users\Ashutosh Singh\Desktop\RedCarpet\1.txt','w') as f:
  2     file = re.sub(r'[^\w]',' ',f)

  ~\Anaconda3\lib\re.py in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
  189     a callable, it's passed the match object and must return
  190     a replacement string to be used."""
  191     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  192 
  193 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: What do you see if you replace the last line with `print(re.sub(r'\W',' ',f.read()))`? (But also replace `'w'` with `'r'` when opening the file, since you need to read it)

Comment: OUTPUT :   io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Comment: See http://rextester.com/ADWHB25313, are you trying like this? Also, note that `ï¼Œ` are *word* chars. If you want to keep only ASCII letters and digits, use `[^A-Za-z0-9]`.

Comment: You may use this: `[\u00BC-\u00EF-\u0152]+` https://regex101.com/r/ICPnW9/2

Comment: How I can use that file in dataframe

Comment: Show all the relevant code you have in the question. And when addressing someone, use `@`+username in the comment.